# add array telephone in existing php form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form in my website, and it works well. It was part of a oakler template and so far I received subject,email,message information back.
I added a telephone field trying to follow the structure of the form but am no php expert and don't know what is not working. 
In the email sent I receive the field 'telephone' but it is empty.

Please help.

The website is this: http://ruidematos.co.uk/contact-psychologist-hypnotherapist-london-harley-street

The form html is this:

```
<form id="contactForm" action="php/contact-form.php" method="POST">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" placeholder="Subject" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" name="subject" id="subject" required>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<textarea maxlength="5000" placeholder="Message" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10" class="form-control input-lg" name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" name="name" id="name" required>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="email" placeholder="Your E-mail" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email" required>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Telephone" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your telephone." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid number." maxlength="30" class="form-control input-lg" name="phone" id="phone" required>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mb-xs" data-loading-text="Loading...">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

The PHP code is this:

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once('php-mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

// Step 1 - Enter your email address below.
$email = 'info@ruidematos.co.uk';

// If the e-mail is not working, change the debug option to 2 | $debug = 2;
$debug = 0;

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$fields = array(
    0 => array(
        'text' => 'Name',
        'val' => $_POST['name']
    ),
    1 => array(
        'text' => 'Email address',
        'val' => $_POST['email']
    ),
    2 => array(
        'text' => 'Message',
        'val' => $_POST['message']
    ),
    3 => array(
        'text' => 'Telephone',
        'val' => $_POST['phone']
    )
);

$message = '';

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
}

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

    $mail->SMTPDebug = $debug;                                 // Debug Mode

    // Step 2 (Optional) - If you don't receive the email, try to configure the parameters below:

    //$mail->IsSMTP();                                         // Set mailer to use SMTP
    //$mail->Host = 'mail.yourserver.com';                     // Specify main and backup server
    //$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                  // Enable SMTP authentication
    //$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                    // SMTP username
    //$mail->Password = 'secret';                              // SMTP password
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                               // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
    //$mail->Port = 587;                                       // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->AddAddress($email);                                 // Add another recipient

    //$mail->AddAddress('person2@domain.com', 'Person 2');     // Add a secondary recipient
    //$mail->AddCC('person3@domain.com', 'Person 3');          // Add a "Cc" address. 
    //$mail->AddBCC('person4@domain.com', 'Person 4');         // Add a "Bcc" address. 

    $mail->SetFrom($email, $_POST['name']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    $mail->Send();
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');

} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->errorMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->getMessage());
}

if ($debug == 0) {
    echo json_encode($arrResult);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the HTML element for `phone` correctly, but it seems the Javascript handler that submits the form has a specified list of elements it fetches, and not the entire form.

Look in http://ruidematos.co.uk/js/views/view.contact.js , within the function `$('#contactForm').validate(` on line 26 the ajax call is performed and submits via POST the 4 elements `name`, `email`, `subject,` ,`message`:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: {
            name: $form.find('#name').val(),
            email: $form.find('#email').val(),
            subject: $form.find('#subject').val(),
            message: $form.find('#message').val()
        }
    })
```

After the `subject` line add one for `phone` too and it should work.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    data: {
        name: $form.find('#name').val(),
        email: $form.find('#email').val(),
        subject: $form.find('#subject').val(),
        phone: $form.find('#phone').val(),
        message: $form.find('#message').val()
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but it still doesn't work, I tried numbers and text and none of them is returned in the email.

Comment: You've written `message: $form.find('#phone').val(),` instead of `phone: $form.find('#phone').val(),`.

Comment: I changed this and still not working. To see it you need to delete cache as is is stored in the browser.

Comment: ok now is working. For some reason the cache was storing the old data. I changed the name of the js file and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your rename message to phone.

```
name: $form.find('#name').val(),
                email: $form.find('#email').val(),
                subject: $form.find('#subject').val(),
                phone: $form.find('#phone').val(),
                message: $form.find('#message').val()
```

Comment: it is renamed to 'phone' but you need to delete cache to see it